# How can i extract the userdata partition of my android emulator?

Tags: android, adb, emulation

How can i extract the (unencrypted and complete) userdata partition of my android emulator (AVD)?

Due to some research i want to extract the userdata and system partition of my emulator. There are several possibilities to do so, yet i was unable to extract a complete and unencrypted userdata partition. I tried the following:

1. Extract using adb pull: `adb pull /dev/block/dm-X DESTINATION_PATH`. Results in being able to analyze the partition using autopsy. The image seems semi-complete as the important folders exist but are basically empty (i am using the SANS digital forensics & incident response poster to look up the most important data).
2. Extract using abd shell: `adb shell "su root dd if=/dev/block/dm-X" > DESTINATION_PATH`. The image seems corrupt. "File system is corrupt (extXfs_group_load: Group 1 descriptor block locations too large at byte offset 4128)" according to fsstat.
3. Access the partition via the file system: `C:\Users\USER\.android\avd\EMULATED_DEVICE_NAME\userdata-qemu.img`. The image seems incomplete as there are only a few folders to analyze.

What's really confusing to me are the three partitions `userdata.img, userdata-qemu.img` and `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2` located in the folder stated in 3). According to the emulator help-page (`emulator -help-disk-images`), `userdata.img` is "the *initial* data partition image". `userdata-qemu.img` is "the persistent data partition image". There is no information about the `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2`. It seems that any data after the initial bootup will be saved in `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2`. I also tried to convert this file using `qemu-img -f qcow2 -O raw userdata-qemu.img.qcow2 userdata.img` to a raw file format (backing file from adb pull (method 1)), which can be analyzed using autopsy. However, the output seemes encrypted as the entropie is very high and you cannot detect any data using xxd/HxD.

I tested this on Android 11 and Android 12 rooted and emulated devices (Google Play API).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know the emulator images with Google Play API are indeed encrypted. QCow2 is the name of the used Quemu encryption system. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196574/2241

Comment: @Robert That did not work for me. The decryption failed as the program was unable to extract any information. According to the Github repository this seems optimized for some older phone and not the emulator/Android 11